Sideways Text/multirow question
I am attempting to insert a table with text rotated 90 degrees, counterclockwise, on the left most column. As of now my table looks like this

With the code
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
         & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Column Player} \\
        \hline
        %\multirow{3}{*}{Row Player} &&& \\
          & \cellcolor{lightgrey} & \cellcolor{lightgrey}$\bm{x=0}$  & \cellcolor{lightgrey}$\bm{x=1}$ \\
        \hline
        \parbox{1.1cm}{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Row \newline Player}}} & \cellcolor{lightgrey} $\bm{x=0}$ & 6 &3 \\[1em]
        \hline
        & \cellcolor{lightgrey} $\bm{x=1}$ & 1 & 10 \\[1em]
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

I'm ultimately trying to get the table to look like this if possible

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!!

Welcome to TeX SE. Could you expand your code to make it compilable? The solution might depend on the package you used.

Like this:

\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{rotating, 
            makecell}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1-2}={3-Z}{},hline{3-Z}={1-Z}{},
             vline{1-2}={3-Z}{},vline{3-Z}={1-Z}{},
             colspec = {*{2}{Q[c,m]}*{2}{Q[c,m, wd=3em]}},
             cell{1}{3} = {c=2}{},
             cell{3}{1} = {r=2}{cmd=\settowidth\rotheadsize{Row Player}\rotcell}, 
             cell{3,4}{2} = {cmd=\settowidth\rotheadsize{$x=0$}\rotcell},
             colsep = 1pt,
             rowsep = 2pt
            }
    &   &   Column Player   
                    &           \\
    &   &   $x=0$   &   $x=1$   \\
Row Player
    &   $x=1$   &   1   &   10  \\   
    &   $x=0$   &   6   &    3  \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}

or this:

\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{rotating, 
            makecell}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines,
             colspec = {*{2}{Q[c,m]}*{2}{Q[c,m, wd=3em]}},
             cell{1}{3} = {c=2}{},
             cell{3}{1} = {r=2}{cmd=\settowidth\rotheadsize{Row Player}\rotcell},
             cell{3,4}{2} = {cmd=\settowidth\rotheadsize{$x=0$}\rotcell},
             colsep = 1pt,
             rowsep = 2pt
            }
    &   &   Column Player
                    &           \\
    &   &   $x=0$   &   $x=1$   \\
Row Player
    &   $x=1$   &   1   &   10  \\
    &   $x=1$   &   6   &    3  \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}

In bot examples are used tabularray, \makecell and rotating packages. The last two are used for rotating of cells contents.

With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.4}
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\rotate}c>{\rotate[c]}ccc}%
  [hvlines,columns-width=auto,corners=NW] % NW = north-west
& & \Block{1-2}{Column Player} \\
  &            & $\bm{x=0}$ & $\bm{x=1}$ \\
\Block{2-1}<\rotate>{Row\\ Player}
  & $\;\bm{x=0}$ & 6          & 3 \\
  & $\;\bm{x=1}$ & 1          & 10 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}


